# How to import from excluded modules (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have a project for a browser app which I want to split in two parts. 
As a minimal example imagine that in ./core I have :

```
// core.js 
import SuperClass from "../core/SuperClass";    
export {SuperClass};

// SuperClass.js
class SuperClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('SuperClass constructor');
    }
}
export default SuperClass
```

and directory ./game has

```
//game.js   
import SuperClass from "../core/SuperClass";
console.log(SuperClass);
```

If I build with game.js as entry point everything is fine as all dependencies go into the bundle.

However, if I exclude the files from ./core (by using exclude function of browserify) and make a separate bundle with them and load before game.js with:

```
<script src="scripts/core.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/game.js"></script>
```

I get : Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../core/SuperClass' from game.js

What is the way to provide those dependencies to game.js at runtime ? My build process uses gulp , babelify and browserify.

Comment: Why do you want to split the application into two separate bundles?

Comment: There's common code that needs to be in a single file loaded by many apps , and there's app specific code , which is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding the code via a `<script>` tag placed before your code, you can assume that is there, as a global variable/class/library, you don't need to import it because it is already present. It's like using the good old JQuery,for example: as you placed the file in your HTML file, you knew that `$` was omnipresent

Comment: Thanks a lot , this seems to work as I need. I guess I had my mindset stuck to the idea that I must import everything. Also I'm new to JS, as may be obvious :) btw if anyone runs into this, you also need to use the standalone option in browserify for this to work